# How many 3D points are needed to define uniqueness a rigid transformation (i.e. rotation+translation)

Tags: coordinate-systems

My intuition would say that, as a transformation is defined by 6 parameters (3 angle for rotation and 3 for translation), a minimum of 2 points in each frame is needed to define uniquely a transformation.

Am I correct?

Comment: 2 definitely can't be right, since $2$ points determine a line segment, and any rotation around that line segment will preserve those points. 3 points will suffice. A set of points will uniquely determine a transformation as long as it has no symmetries (possibly no symmetries preserving the points pointwise, depending on if the points are labeled or not). Then a scalene triangle can't be mapped to itself by any combination of 3d rotations or translations in any way except by the identity.

Comment: Only if the segment is aligned to an axis we would have this problem no?

Comment: A rotation about any axis can be expressed as a combination of translations and rotations.

Comment: Translate the off center axis to the origin, rotate around the axis, and translate the axis back.

Comment: @jgon  How will three points suffice if you need three points just to determine the rotation itself, without the extra translation vector?

Comment: @uniquesolution Each source-destination point pair supplies two independent constraints and there are six degrees of freedom. There’s always the caveat that these points must be “in general position,” of course.